# Identity Server 4: force user to login with provider after he closes the browser/tab

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have an Angular app and an ASP.NET Core web API which are using the code flow client with PKCE flow with Identity Server 4 to authenticate users (using Facebook or Microsoft provider). If the user logs on, the access token is renewed with the refresh token succesfully (silent refresh), so the user can work without interruptions.

However, if the user does not sign out, and just closes the browser or the browser's tab; and he goes to the site again, he is automatically logged on when he clicks log on, instead of asking for the provider to log on with. Because the cookie 'idsrv' is still valid. The idsrv cookie is used for ASP.NET Core Cookie Authentication.

If I log out explicitely, it all works correctly and idsrv and idsrv-session cookies are deleted.

My question is: how can I force the user to log on again if he closed the browser, to make sure that the next user (for example on a public computer) cannot use his credentials?

EDIT: I cannot delete the cookie client-side, as it's a HTTP-only cookie.

**CONCLUSION**: I have detected the root cause. There was actually nothing wrong with the cookie: it was a session cookie, so it should have been deleted when the browser closes. However, this did not happen because I had enabled the browser setting 'continue where you left off', so it remembered the tabs that were open including the cookies. I turned off this feature and cookies were deleted fine.

Comment: Did you try to make the cookie expiration time to be "session"?

Comment: No, not sure how to configure that in IdentityServer

Comment: You just need to set expiration of your cookie to be null so the browser will automatically mark it as a Session cookie

Comment: Yes, it was already a session cookie. See my edit.

Comment: Perfect also keep in mind ,Many web browsers have a session restore feature that will save all tabs and restore them next time the browser is used. Session cookies will also be restored, as if the browser was never closed.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

Answer (score 0):

You need to first import `HostListener` from `'@angular/core'`

Use `window unload` event, listen to this event via `HostListner` in your app/root component

```
  @HostListener('window:unload', [ '$event' ])
  unloadHandler(event) {
        // write your remove token/userdetails logic here
        // e.g localStorage.removeItem('token');
  }
```

Comment: But OnDestroy is not called when you close the window, or is it?

Comment: No, I am debugging my own answer will shortly modify my answer.

Comment: Now everytime tab/browser close event will be listened to and can apply your logic when event captured.

Comment: Thanks, I indeed tried this in the App component, but it seems this is not called at all when I close the browser. I'm looking into what could be wrong.

Comment: Ah wait, it is called, it just doesn't show the alert(''). I will try to delete cookies from here.

Comment: It is indeed called when browser/tab closed i have tested it.

Comment: but one drawback is that one you are navigating to extenal link and then coming back to any application route, it will also be treated as window unload event

Comment: How can you see a alert when tab/browser is closed, can use a debugger for that that too i doubt!

Comment: Not yet. I can delete normal cookies, but the cookie I want to delete is a HTTP-only cookie (contains token for identity server), which is not returned with document.cookie. So it seems I cannot delete it, but I'm researching further. I guess I have to do it server-side or something.

Comment: If you make that cookie a session cookie (i.e. don't set an expiry time) then it will be removed when the browser is closed. If you just close the tab it will stick around however.

Comment: Thanks. So I should somehow configure identity server that this idsrv cookie becomes a session cookie...?

Comment: Don't keep token in cookie use storage instead.